# Como inserir um arquivo dentro de um array

Tags: php, array, rotas

estou com uma dificuldade e não consegui resolver.
Tenho um arquivo de configurações nesse arquivo tenho um array e vários arrays dentro dele e um desses é meu array de rotas. O que eu preciso fazer é incluir um arquivo dentro desse array de rotas porque tenho muitas rotas e quero separar por arquivos para facilitar a manutenção depois. bom, o que eu tenho é isso:

routes.php

```
return array(
    'dependencias' => [
        // array de dependências
    ],

    'routes' => [
        // array de rotas que eu quero inserir
    ]

);
```

rotas.php

```
[
'name' => 'home',
'path' => '/',
'middleware' => Site\Action\HomePageAction::class,
'allowed_methods' => ['GET'],
],
```

o que eu preciso é incluir o arquivo rotas.php dentro do array routes. Alguém já fez isso ou sabe como fazer?

Grato

Answer (score 1):

Inclui normalmente o arquivo na chave do `array` do arquivo de configuração.

**routes.php**

```
return [
    'routes' => [
        'minhasRotas' => require "rotas.php",
    ]
];
```

Define que seu arquivo ira retornar um `array`.

**rotas.php**

```
return [
    [
        'name' => 'home',
        'path' => '/',
        'middleware' => Site\Action\HomePageAction::class,
        'allowed_methods' => ['GET'],
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'login',
        'path' => '/login',
        'middleware' => Site\Action\LoginAction::class,
        'allowed_methods' => ['GET'],
    ],
    [...],
    [...],
];
```

Comment: Opa.. obrigado por responder... certo.. pra uma rota funcionou mesmo, mas agora o meu problema é que preciso colocar várias rotas dentro de um arquivo, por exemplo: nesse arquivo rotas, vai ficar as rotas de login então vai ter a rota login, auth, admin e logout.. como faço para retornar um array de cada rota? eu testei colocando cada rota entre [ ] mas não funcionou :(

Comment: Opa, veja se a alteração que fiz contempla sua dúvida.

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso mas não funcionou.. porque só pode ter um array dentro do route e depois os arrays com as rotas e assim dessa forma existe um array a mais antes do array com as rotas. não sei o que fazer..

Comment: Consegui fazer como eu queria usando o array_merge(), ele junta vários arrays dentro de um só.. Obrigado a todos